# Terminal OS X export command not working, cannot set new variable/pathway

Tags: terminal, mac, command-line, path

I'm trying to set a variable, e.g.

```
BIN=../../../../bin
```

but I get

```
BIN=../../../../bin: Command not found.
```

The same for

```
export BIN
export: Command not found.
```

It seems that I can't edit the path which looks incorrect...

```
echo $PATH /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/home/tmp
```

What might be wrong please?

Comment: Are you using `csh` (or `tcsh`) by any chance?

Comment: How do I tell if I am please? (I'm very new to using terminal!)

Comment: Does `setenv foo bar` work or throw an error?

Comment: @patrix seems to work!

Comment: So it's `csh`/`tcsh` then, but you are using commands aimed at `bash`. As you are new to Terminal I wonder how you ended up with `csh` in the first place. What is the actual goal here, aka why exactly do you need to edit PATH?

Comment: Think I managed to fix it using `chsh -s /bin/bash`. Thank you for your help and for pointing out I was using `csh/tsch`!